# cypress tests paralellization in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, cypress, bitbucket, package.json

i have test files under cypress/e2e/Test/examples. i want to run them paralelly, but the configuration of cypress does not work in ci (normal test run too). so i started to use following structure to run my tests. my problem is that i can not run those test files under examples folder paralelly. is it possible to run them paralelly?

```
    image: cypress/browsers:node-18.15.0-chrome-111.0.5563.146-1-ff-111.0.1-edge-111.0.1661.62-1


examples: &examples
  name: Run examples
  caches:
    - node
    - cypress
  script:
    - npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/Test/examples/*.js"
  artifacts:
    # store any generates images and videos as artifacts
    - cypress/screenshots/**
    - cypress/videos/**
    - cypress/reports/**



pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      name: Install dependencies
      caches:
        - npm
        - cypress
        - node
      script:
        - npm ci

  - parallel:
    - step:
        <<: *examples


definitions:
  caches:
    npm: $HOME/.npm
    cypress: $HOME/.cache/Cypress
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/bitbucket-pipelines
those solitions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

first i could not find a way to run cypress test files parallely in bitbucket pipeline without cypress cloud. it has record limit, so if you want to run more test, you need to pay.

```
script:
- npx cypress run --record --key yourRecordKey --parallel --ci-build-id yourProjectId $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

be careful indent, .yml takes it into consideration. after that you expand the nodes as much as you want (it depends on your bitbucket pipeline account limit).

```
  - parallel:
    - step:
    <<: *examples
    - step:
    <<: *examples
    - step:
    <<: *examples
```

you can add more.
if there will be an another way to run the test files parallely in remote, please share here too.